Nginx (failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR with file upload
I've configured nginx reverse proxy on server my backend is written on FastAPI python.
On file upload receiving the following error on browser network:
(failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Following is my nginx configuration:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name demo.snabup.com;
    gzip off;`

    ssl_certificate somekey.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key someprivatekey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 50M;  # Adjust the maximum allowed body size
    client_body_timeout 60s;
    client_header_timeout 60s;
    keepalive_timeout 60s;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_send_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
    }
}

I've tried without file upload and it is working fine the problem is with if I send the file in API, not getting any logs in nginx.service neither in FastAPI uvicorn.service
